# Function to add UIGesture automatically executes the button method in override function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, overriding

I have the following problem:

In my viewDidLoad() I have this code:

```
    self.singleTapVar.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.singleTapVar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.singleTapFunc))
    self.touchUpRect.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.touchUpRect.addGestureRecognizer(self.singleTapVar)
```

I want to call this for more than one view so I wrote the function:

```
    func addTapToView(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer, view: UIView, method: Void, numberOfTaps: Int){
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTaps
        tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.method))
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

And then call this function in my override function:

```
    addTapToView(tap: singleTapVar, view: touchUpRect, method: singleTapFunc(), numberOfTaps: 1)
```

The problem is, when the code is embedded in a function and then called in the override function, it is automatically executed at the first launch of my app and **the button is tapped**, which does not happen if its normally coded and it should not happen...

Thanks in advance and best regards
Fabi

Comment: which button? You mean to say when you call tap gesture function in viewDidLoad() it executes tap by its own??

Comment: The question is already answered, but fyi it executed the function which is called when you pressed the button (touchUpRect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing your selector to your function, you're calling it and passing the result to the function.

You should change your function to take a `Selector` instead of `Void`:

```
func addTapToView(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer, view: UIView, method: Selector, numberOfTaps: Int){
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTaps
    tap.addTarget(self, action: method)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

And then pass the selector when you call the function:

```
addTapToView(tap: singleTapVar, view: touchUpRect, method: #selector(ViewController.singleTapFunc), numberOfTaps: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method, you invoke singleTapFunc() before you tap on your view

```
addTapToView(tap: singleTapVar, view: touchUpRect, method: singleTapFunc(), numberOfTaps: 1)
```

remove it, and invoke singleTapFunc() in addTapToView(:,:,:) method

```
func addTapToView(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer, view: UIView, numberOfTaps: Int){
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTaps
        tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.singleTapFunc))
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need a parameter for the method/selector, too. :)